# JS проверить возможность ctr+z

Tags: javascript

Можно ли в Js проверить возможность нажатия ctr+z? то есть если например изменили что то на странице, то можно отменить нажав ctr+z , как отследить что в этом буфере undo что то есть? 
Вот пример

```
<button id="undo" title="ctrl + Z" >Undo</button><button id="redo" title="ctrl + Y" disabled>Redo</button>
<div class="phones" contenteditable="true"><span>8 (925) 505-55-55</span>
<br /><span>8 (925) 505-55-55</span></div>
```

при изменения текста хотелось бы чтобы кнопки могли изменять активность

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n5vnprfn/ вот пример на jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4evryocd/2/ - так можно проверять нажатие ctrl+z

Answer (score 1):

Нужно завести отдельную переменную `var stringBuffer` и при каждом нажатии помещать туда текст. Если нужна возможность отменять несколько раз, то нужен список, куда при каждом новом изменении текста добавлять новый элемент в конец. Чтобы зарегестрировать изменение, нужно отслеживать ситуации, когда пользователь ничего не печатает, к примеру, 2 секунды, после чего сравнивать последний элемент списка с тем, что пользователь имеет на экране.